# OnBackKeyPress is not working as expected

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In my app I have these two functions. Ever since I added the `OnBackKeyPress` function, the `if` statement inside `OnNavigatedFrom` is true even if I press back button (may be because `e.cancel= true;` inside `OnBackKeyPress`).

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   // On back navigation there is no need to save state.
   if (e.NavigationMode != System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationMode.Back)
   {
      StoreState(); //this should not run when i press back button
   }

   FilterPreviewPivot.SelectionChanged -= FilterPreviewPivot_SelectionChanged;
   base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}

protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
   while (NavigationService.CanGoBack) NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Chooser.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

   // cancel the navigation
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: @lhan16 i tried setting break point inside if statement and pressed back key. The statement was running. I feel e.cancel is the reason most probably. And wouldn't removing it would cause problem. as it will go back to backstack and also chooser.xaml at same time

Comment: I see, you will want to keep `e.cancel` then. So what is the value of `e.NavigationMode` inside `OnNavigatedFrom` then?

Comment: @lhan16 and its 'new' even when i press windows button.

Comment: Maybe you can just create a Global variable called `wentBack`, which is set to `false` by default, and then in `OnBackKeyPress` you can set it to `true`. In `OnNavigatedFrom` you could check if `wentBack == true`, you know the user tapped "Back".

Comment: @lhan16 it worked. i set 'Back' to false in OnNavigatedTo function

Comment: Glad to have helped, I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're setting `e.cancel = true` in `OnBackKeyPress`, the `NavigationMode` won't be `Back` in `OnNavigatedFrom`.

Try using a global variable in your page which is `false` by default, and set it to `true` in `OnBackKeyPress`. Then, in `OnNavigatedFrom` check for this variable instead of `NavigationMode.Back`.